Help with optimizing virtual method
I am developing a key / value database
https://github.com/nmmmnu/HM4
Currently I have following commands

XNSUM - sum keys with same prefix
XRSUM - sum keys from some range
XNCOUNT - count keys with same prefix
XRCOUNT - count keys from some range

All this works well, except I have way too many commands - 10+
Now I have idea to add some more, so I want this to look like this:

XNPIPE prefix     | SUM
XRPIPE start stop | SUM
XNPIPE prefix     | COUNT
XRPIPE start stop | COUNT

For this I need to do some "API" / interface with virtual methods of function pointers.
Here is very basic idea.
Some reduce commands will require a copy of the input data to be made. (no real copy is done, but I store like 100'000 pointers to objects in array)
Then these will be done as user_map_copy which is very efficient with single vtable call.
Yes all data is copied but that's OK, because is required for other reasons.
However other operations, for example sum and count, does not need "copy" of the input and "copy" will be waste. But if we do not copy, we have to do 100'000 vtable call - user_map.
Because those 100'000 vtable call are to the same object, there should be something I can do, so these calls to be devirtualized. I can guarantee I wont change the vtable between the calls :)
user_map_test - here I am trying to devirtualize the call, without success.
Any idea how I can make user_map more optimal?
I am using C++17.

#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

struct BaseReducer{
    std::size_t result = 0;

    virtual void map(int a) = 0;
    virtual void map_range(const int *begin, const int *end) = 0;

    // no need the d-tor, but for completeness
    virtual ~BaseReducer() = default;
};

auto user_map(const int *begin, const int *end, BaseReducer &r){
    r.result = 0;

    for(auto it = begin; it != end; ++it){
        r.map(*it);
        // much more logic here
    }
    
    return r.result;
}

auto user_map_test(const int *begin, const int *end, BaseReducer &r){
    r.result = 0;

    void (BaseReducer::*f)(int) = &BaseReducer::map;

    for(auto it = begin; it != end; ++it)
        (r.*f)(*it);

    return r.result;
}

auto user_map_copy(const int *begin, const int *end, BaseReducer &r){
    // here we copy the elements and pass it to the BaseReducer
    // example is very basic so we do not copy, but real code does copy
    // and store pointers to real objects because they are very big.

    r.result = 0;

    int vector[5]; // let suppose know magically know the size

    std::copy(begin, end, vector);

    // ugly because we need pointers to iterate
    r.map_range(std::begin(vector), std::end(vector));

    return r.result;
}

struct SumReducer : BaseReducer{
    void map(int a) final{
            map_(a);
    }

    void map_range(const int *begin, const int *end) final{
        for(auto it = begin; it != end; ++it)
            map_(*it);
    }

private:
    void map_(int){
            ++result;
    }
};

struct CountReducer : BaseReducer{
    void map(int a) final{
            ++result;
    }

    void map_range(const int *begin, const int *end) final{
        result = static_cast<std::size_t>(end - begin);
    }
};

#include <iterator>

int main() {
    const int data[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    CountReducer cr;

    user_map(std::begin(data), std::end(data), cr);

    std::cout << cr.result << '\n';

    user_map_copy(std::begin(data), std::end(data), cr);

    std::cout << cr.result << '\n';
}


Have you done any profiling/benchmarking/measurements?

Repeating that. Have you measured the speed? 100,000 virtual calls to the same implementation don’t take more than a millisecond.

What makes you think you can do a better job in optimizing those 100000 calls than the optimizer that works much closer to the CPU? Hoisting invariant instructions out of a loop is a very common optimization.

Aside: Your example SumReducer counts it's input, it doesn't sum it

@Caleth yes, it seems that way. I did it just for demonstration

@Nick: I see you are here, writing comments, still did not reply to the two very first questions asked - so let me repeat this: have you measured the speed? If the answer is "no", the most sensible answer is probably "you are overthinking this".

yes I did - user_map - fast enough :) ,  user_map_test = twice slow than user_map, CountReducer::map_range = about 10% faster than user_map.

Since modern CPUs are able to do branch prediction also for indirect calls, the performance difference is no longer substantial.

Is it possible to implement everything via map_range and remove map from the public interface? If that's feasible, then the problem goes away.

@FilipMilovanović no it can not. I will even be forced to remove this method, by different reason. But seems vtable call speed is good enought.

I bet it doesn’t make a difference. If it does: Implement your function with a non virtual inline function named inline_f which has a T* pthis as the first argument and put it in the header file. Then call this instead of the virtual function, so inline_f (obj, args) instead of obj->f(args). To avoid code duplication implement f as inline_f(this, args).
This removes the virtual function call, and the non-virtual call, and allows optimisations if some of the arguments have known values.

inline_f(this, args) = can you give me an example, because I do not understand what exactly you mean?

see my answer to the question

When you say inline, you mean in reality a free aka non-member  function, isn't it ? The question is then why the base class had an abstract member in the first place...

As far as I know, the current optimizers are already able to remove virtual calls if the type can be known. And for sure,  from performance point of view, the free function with the pointer argument and a non-virtual member function will make absolutely no difference and generate almost the same code.

If you always have access to the fully-derived type you are using, you don't need virtual functions at all.
struct BaseReducer{
    std::size_t result = 0;
};

// CountReducer and SumReducer as before, but final qualifiers are not needed or allowed

template <typename Reducer>
auto user_map(const int *begin, const int *end, Reducer& r){
    r.result = 0;

    for(auto it = begin; it != end; ++it){
        r.map(*it);
        // much more logic here
    }
    
    return r.result;
}

template <typename Reducer>
auto user_map_copy(const int *begin, const int *end, Reducer& r){
    // here we copy the elements and pass it to the BaseReducer
    // example is very basic so we do not copy, but real code does copy
    // and store pointers to real objects because they are very big.
    r.result = 0;
   
    int vector[5]; // let suppose know magically know the size

    std::copy(begin, end, vector);

    // ugly because we need pointers to iterate
    r.map_range(std::begin(vector), std::end(vector));

    return r.result;
}

int main() {
    const int data[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    CountReducer cr;

    user_map(std::begin(data), std::end(data), cr);

    std::cout << cr.result << '\n';

    user_map_copy(std::begin(data), std::end(data), cr);

    std::cout << cr.result << '\n';
}


templates - yes. this is kind of how it works at the moment, but this wont work if the end user have to choose the type of the reduce command.

@Nick yes it can. switch (userInput) case Count: do_pipeline<CountReducer>(); break; case Sum: do_pipeline<SumReducer>(); break; etc

@Nick or probably more scalably: std::variant<Reducer1, Reducer2, ...> input_one = gather_input_one(); std::variant<ReducerA, ReducerB, ...> input_two = gather_input_two(); ... std::visit(do_pipeline, input_one, input_two, ...);

yes, I am thinking about this way too. but then the modules will be more coupled because they will be part of the type, this is something I want to avoid

They are only more coupled if you are separately compiling your project. user_map doesn't depend on the concrete reducer types, it still only depends on the abstraction. The code calling user_map, which is already coupled to the concrete types, remains coupled to the concrete types.

Rather than being an abstract class, BaseReducer becomes a requirement. In C++20 you define a concept to reify that requirement

yes, but all template types must be known in comile time. (believe me I know what you mean, 99.99 % of the cases I am using templates)

@Nick using std::variant will at least condense your 100000 virtual calls down into one

yes, but all reducer classes must be known in the same compilation unit.

@Nick yes, the compilation unit with main in it. Or whatever composition root you have. That isn't problematic coupling

@Nick the alternative is sticking with the status quo. Is a 10% performance degradation worse than this coupling?

no, because I have some ideas which if not refactor will be executed very poorly
